# Bash reading socket /dev/rfcomm0

Tags: bash, sockets, bluetooth, disconnect

I'm working on processing data I get from my android app trough the Bluetooth socket of my raspberry.

Long story short I am able to make a connection, send data(JSON string). I can read the data when I tail/cat in the socket located at */dev/rfcomm0* but when I put this inside a script to constantly check if the file has new data I don't understand how to automatically stop reading the socket. I'm trying to write 3 to the var *input*:

Exec 3<>/dev/rfcomm0
 3

But I actually need to send the received JSON string to another program. So I need to quit reading everytime a JSON string arrived and start the last process  with the JSON string.

I understand this is normal for starting to reading a socket but I've watched all over to find a way to stop reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you stop reading? What you seem to need is

```
while read input ; do
    do_something_with "$input"
done <&3
```

In this way, the shell continues to read, and for every line you can send the string to another program.

If your `other_program` reads stdin, you may consider using a fifo for that:

```
mkfifo fifootje
cat fifootje  | other_program &
while read input ; do
    echo "$input" >>fifootje
done <&3
```

Comment: Looks good. Don't have time at the moment. I'll let you know later on if it fixed the problem.

Comment: You were right. At the time I had not enough bash knowledge. It is important to understand the difference between a basic file and a socket.